# Проблема с CodeBlocks не запускает программы

Tags: codeblocks, компиляция, c++

Установил `CodeBlocks(12.11)` в новый ноутбук c Windows 8. Но он не запускает программы.
При включении выдаёт такую ошибку:

> Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's for OpenWatcom (W32) Compiler

Comment: Я установил с mingw 17.12 но всё равно ошибка . Но не может найти папку bin

Comment: Куда вставить скачанную программу кодеблокс 17,12 на папку С/ ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите компилятор.
Или скачайте сборку вместе с компилятором.

Например тут 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/12.11/Windows/codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe/download

Comment: Я скачал и установил codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup_user.exe

Comment: @Nikfilv, сейчас не могу посмотреть, там должны быть настройки компилятора. Как-то нужно отключить Watcom и включить MinGW

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Меню Settings - Compiler - Выбрать GNU GCC - Нажать set as default?

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках где компилятор сбросил настройки - Reset defaults, и мне помогло. Еще галку на желаемый компилятор.